# Changing style through hover?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have modified the text with the property: visibility and it does not work :-(

I have this simple code, but it is not working:

```js
$("#text").hover(function() {      
                   //mouse enter
                   $("#blackbox").css({   
                        "visibility": "visible"
                     });
                  },
                  function(){
                   //mouse leave
                   $("#blackbox").css({   
                      "visibility": "hidden"
                   });
              });
```

```css
#text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#blackbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3><a href="#" id"text">Pasa el ratón:</a></h3>
  <div id="blackbox"></div>
</body>
```

Not working
What is the problem?

How do I, so that when the mouse passes the link, the picture changes color?

Comment: **1.** You're missing the `#` in `$("#blackbox")`. **2.** Better be achieved using CSS. **3.** You can use jQuery's `hover()` that expects two functions as arguments, one for the `mousein` and one for the `mouseout`.

Comment: Why not use `:hover` in CSS?

Comment: @haim770 $("#text").mousein(function() {
    $("#blackbox").css( {
    "background-color": "yellow"
   });   
});
$("#text").mouseout(function() {
     $("#blackbox").css( { 
    "background-color": "black"
    }); 
});

Comment: @Roberrrt Because it affects another element

Comment: @IsaacPalacio Let me answer this with the magic of the `+` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use .hover(handleIn, handleOut) instead of.
In addition, be careful of your jQuery selectors.

`$("#blackbox")` will select tag with `id="blackbox"`

`$("blackbox")` will select the tag blackbox

`<blackbox></blackbox>`

```js
$("#text").hover(function() {
    //mouse enter
    $("#blackbox").css({    
        "background-color": "yellow"
    });
},  
function() {
    //mouse leave
 $("#blackbox").css({     
        "background-color": "black"
 });
});
```

```css
#text {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:24px;
}

#blackbox {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;    
}
```

```html
  <h3><a href="#" id="text">Pasa el ratón:</a></h3>
  <div id="blackbox"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have modified the text with the property: visibility and it does not work :-(

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so we all know that parent selectors don't exist in CSS, however, we *do* have the sibling selector `+` in CSS, which is a way easier solution than reverting to jQuery/JavaScript.

Given the following HTML syntax, we can create a hover using pure CSS:

```css
#text {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:24px;
}

#blackbox {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;    
}

#text:hover + #blackbox {
 background-color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="text"><a href="#">Pasa el ratón:</a></h3>
<div id="blackbox"></div>
```

I did change the `id="text"` to your `h3` parent element, because the `a` isn't a sibling of your `#blackbox`.

Comment: The behaviour changes a little bit ... If you hover to the right of the **a**, the hover is triggered. This is because the **h3** is wider than the **a**

Comment: hi @Roberrrt, with property visibility: visible; it does not work

Comment: @IsaacPalacio and which element should hold that property?

Comment: @Roberrrt #text {
   font-weight: 600;
  font-size:24px;
}

#blackbox {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 100px;    
}

#text:hover + #blackbox {
 visibility: visible;
}

Comment: That's odd, it works in my codepen, did you update the HTML accordingly?
http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/RoLWEq

Comment: @Roberrrt It works, there was a small error in the html thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please, never use `if-else` for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functionality, you have specific functions to do so:

```
$("#text").on("hover", function(e) {
   //on entering
    $("blackbox").css(  {                               
        "background-color": "yellow"
    });  
   //on leaving 
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        $("blackbox").css(  {                               
            "background-color": "black"
        });     
    });
});
```

*I hope it helps*